# Java Server Problem

Tags: server, java, xubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java 6/7 JRE or JDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

I want to make server with Xubuntu but i don't know anything about Linux, So is there any software which can install Java Jre 7 automatically. -Windows uses too Much Ram-

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. Run the following command in Terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

### Quick tip

When you're searching for a program like this, try the following command:

```
apt-cache search keywords here
```

So for instance,

```
apt-cache search jre 7
```

Gives this:

```
icedtea-7-jre-jamvm - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using JamVM
openjdk-7-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-7-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-7-jre-lib - OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
openjdk-7-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark
```

You may then use common sense to figure out which package to install.